# Extract info from many tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I've got one 'main' table and many 'slaves' of same level. There are no primary or foreign keys.

I know list of slave's names only from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Master table has fields 'NameMC' (mostly unique), 'Price', 'Developer' (multiple of same) and an empty field 'Description'.

Slaves tables are named as field 'Developer' from above and have field 'Name' which is loosely resembles 'NameMC'. This is how they connected. They also have field 'Description' with needed information inside.

I need to extract all Descriptions from all this tables, combine with master table and receive final array.

When I do select like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM main
LEFT JOIN slave1 ON Developer = 'slave1'
AND NameMC LIKE CONCAT('%',Name,'%')
GROUP BY NameMC
```

I got what I need what I need but only for one slave table: I extract description for given Developer. But I need to extract all descriptions from all slave's tables in the same way and combine them in one array.

When I do multiple left joins, it doesn't work because after each step all filled with info from this last step, so NULL's in all Description fields except for last Developer.